# Serialize table data as IEnumerable within asp.net WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api application , in which I have this code

```
  public class FiltredDriverAgendaModel
    {
        public int Id_driver_agenda { get; set; }
        public string name_driver_agenda { get; set; }
        public bool isDriveChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

**Html part**

```
<table id="tbldriver" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr style="color:white;background-color:#3c8dbc">
                                                    <th>Id chauffeur</th>
                                                    <th>Chauffeur</th>
                                                    <th> </th>

                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="tbldriverBody"></tbody>
                                        </table>
```

I fill this table in the javascript part like this :

```
 function GetFiltredDrivers() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/api/AccountManage/GetAllChauffeurs",
            success: function (data) {
                EmptyGridFilter();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var chauffeur = data[i];   
                    $('#tbldriverBody').append('<tr><td><input type="text" readonly name="Id_driver_agenda" value="'+ chauffeur.id+'" />  </td>'
                   + '<td><input type="text"  name="name_driver_agenda" readonly value="' + chauffeur.Nom + " " + chauffeur.Prenom + '" /></td>'
                   + '<td><input type="checkbox"  name="isDriveChecked" checked /> </td></tr>');
                }
                initGridDriver();

                } 
        });
    }
function initGridDriver() {
    var table = $('#tbldriver').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/French.json" },
        "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 250, 500, -1], [50, 250, 500, "Tout"]],
        "destroy": true,
        "columnDefs": [
   { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
    { "width": "50%", "targets": 1 },
     { "width": "30%", "targets": 2 } 

        ],
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });

    $("#tbldriver tr").css('cursor', 'pointer');

    $('#tbldriverBody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected'); 
        }
        else {

            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass();
            $(this).addClass('selected'); 

        }

    });

}
```

And I made this Ajax call :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        url: "/api/Demande/ReservationAgendaByDrivers",
        data: $("#tbldriver input").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
      .............
       }
```

The problem is when I create the service `ReservationAgendaByDrivers` like this :

```
[HttpPost]
        public IEnumerable<ReservationModel> ReservationAgendaByDrivers(List<FiltredDriverAgendaModel> obj) {}
```

I get this problem : always `obj` takes `null` as a value.

So I need to know :

1. What is the type of controller's parameter that I have to choose?
2. Why the value is null?
3. How can I fix my code?

Thanks,

Comment: I would check the posted data by the ajax call first, by developer tools / network tab of the browser. Can you paste it as well? Or you can just alert it or write it to the console log.

Comment: @OguzOzgul this the data `Id_driver_agenda=15&name_driver_agenda=driver2aj+driver2aj&Id_driver_agenda=14&name_driver_agenda=driver1aj+driver1aj&Id_driver_agenda=11&name_driver_agenda=ledriver+ledriver&isDriveChecked=on&Id_driver_agenda=7&name_driver_agenda=afifement+afifement&isDriveChecked=on&Id_driver_agenda=5&name_driver_agenda=special+special&isDriveChecked=on&Id_driver_agenda=1&name_driver_agenda=driverkkkk+driver&isDriveChecked=on`

Comment: It says that, the serialize method creates a query string like data, which will never converted to a list of your own class. The method body for initgriddriver is also required here to help.

Comment: Since you are dynamically generating those rows, I think it is better to read the posted values through the form, because you can never create a method signature to type strictly get all of the parameters, may be getting it as a namevaluecollection can help

Comment: @OguzOzgul see plz my edit. what do u suggest to fix this?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: The link is very useful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your inputs correctly.

I've tried the following and it worked for me- simply replace the 'name' attribute of your input in obj[index].property like this:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" readonly name="obj['+i+'].id" value="'+ chauffeur.id+'" />  </td>'
               + '<td><input type="text"  name="obj['+i+'].Nom" ...
```

(assuming .id and .Nom are properties in your model)